# What does "something built entirely within the type system" mean?

Tags: typescript

A while ago I saw a tweet of someone who implemented flappy bird entirely within the type system, I looked at the code and it was in typescript but I couldn't understand much.

types are for adding explicit indication of what a type is and generics make the type system a bit more functional but that's it, as far as I know, a type system in typescript can't execute actual code, so how is that done?

Comment: Is the the project you mention? https://zackoverflow.dev/writing/flappy-bird-in-type-level-typescript/ Because from the readme it says "I created a type-level Typescript runtime, allowing Typescript types to be run outside of the Typescript compiler/language server. This “runtime” is a custom VM implemented in Zig, which executes a custom bytecode format I compile Typescript code into." So they actually wrote an execution environment for Typescript type so that they work at runtime. This is not normal.

Comment: @AlexWayne Yes that's the one! I scimmed through the tweet and couldn't find it again so that's my bad. I learned intersting stuff about TS nonetheless!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typescript types can't "execute actual code" at runtime, but they can still express relationships and transformations. It's actually a lot like functional programming.

```
type Transform<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: {
    value: T[K]
  }
}
type A = { foo: string, bar: string }
type B = Transform<A>
// { foo: { value: string }, bar: { value: string } }
```

In this silly example `Transform` can be thought of as a "function" that accept a parameter named `T`, which "returns" another type that is derived from `T`.

This is sort of like a program that runs at *compile time*, not runtime. The above Typescript code compiles to an empty file, because it contains no executable runtime code.

So the above code could described as something "entirely within the type system".

Now is this *useful* if it never touches executable code? Probably not. But this sort of thing serves as a showcase for Typescript's power to describe complex behavior with types.

---

One of the best examples I've seen of this is [ts-sql](https://github.com/codemix/ts-sql) which implements a SQL database, complete with SQL query parsing.

```
import { Query } from "@codemix/ts-sql";

const db = {
  things: [
    { id: 1, name: "a", active: true },
    { id: 2, name: "b", active: false },
    { id: 3, name: "c", active: true },
  ],
} as const;

type ActiveThings = Query<
  "SELECT id, name AS nom FROM things WHERE active = true",
  typeof db
>;

// ActiveThings is now equal to the following type:
type Expected = [{ id: 1; nom: "a" }, { id: 3; nom: "c" }];
```

You provide a database state, which is a type. Then you query it with string literal types, which returns more types. So just like my simple example above, you have types that you pass to other types, to output yet more types that are logical derivations on the input types.

So again, is this useful in a real app? Probably not. It's really cool though!

Answer (score 3):

You can write TypeScript types that are so complex that in order for the compiler to compute them, it has to do the equivalent of running an arbitrary computer program.  It isn't as easily expressive as JavaScript, but it has everything you need to do so:

- TypeScript has [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) types of the form `type F<T, U, V> = ⋯` which can be used like *type functions*; the type equivalent of the JavaScript `const f = (t, u, v) => ⋯`.
- TypeScript has [conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) of the form `X extends Y ? A : B` which can be used like *conditionals*; the type equivalent of the JavaScript `x === y ? a : b`.
- TypeScript has [variadic tuple types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-0.html#variadic-tuple-types) of the form `[...A, ...B, C]` which can be used like *array [spreads](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)*; the type equivalent of the JavaScript `[...a, ...b, c]`.
- TypeScript has [template literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#template-literal-types) of the form `` `${A}bc${D}` `` which can be used to *concatenate strings*;  the type equivalent of the JavaScript `` `${a}bc${d}` ``.

There are more, but that is enough to demonstrate.  Even before some of these features were introduced, the TypeScript type system was considered [Turing-complete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_completeness).  See [microsoft/TypeScript#14833](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14833)

---

The [FizzBuzz program](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fizz_buzz) is a commonly referenced coding exercise where you enumerate positive numbers from 1 to (usually) 100, but instead of saying multiples of three you say "Fizz"`, and instead of saying multiples of five you say "Buzz", and if it's a multiple of both you say "FizzBuzz".  Let's write a version of this program that only uses the above-mentioned JavaScript features (more or less):

```
const fizzBuzz = (
  n: number = 101,
  c3: any[] = [0],
  c5: any[] = [0],
  a: any[] = [0],
  s: string = ""): string =>
  a.length === n ? s : fizzBuzz(
    n,
    c3.length === 2 ? [] : [0, ...c3],
    c5.length === 4 ? [] : [0, ...c5],
    [0, ...a],
    `${s}${s === "" ? "" : " "}${c3.length === 0 ?
      c5.length === 0 ? "FizzBuzz" : "Fizz" :
      c5.length === 0 ? "Buzz" : a.length
    }`);
```

If we run that in JavaScript, we can see this:

```
console.log(fizzBuzz());
/* "1 2 Fizz 4 Buzz Fizz 7 8 Fizz Buzz 11 Fizz 13 14 FizzBuzz 16 17 Fizz 
    19 Buzz Fizz 22 23 Fizz Buzz 26 Fizz 28 29 FizzBuzz 31 32 Fizz 34 Buzz 
    Fizz 37 38 Fizz Buzz 41 Fizz 43 44 FizzBuzz 46 47 Fizz 49 Buzz Fizz 52 
    53 Fizz Buzz 56 Fizz 58 59 FizzBuzz 61 62 Fizz 64 Buzz Fizz 67 68 Fizz 
    Buzz 71 Fizz 73 74 FizzBuzz 76 77 Fizz 79 Buzz Fizz 82 83 Fizz Buzz 86 
    Fizz 88 89 FizzBuzz 91 92 Fizz 94 Buzz Fizz 97 98 Fizz Buzz" */
```

[Playground link to JS code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noErrorTruncation=true#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZgSwF5IEIFcUwLwwBQCwAUDDGAFxnoC2ARgKYBOOMAjAAysA0xpwAzJQCGYAJ4BtALotx7STxIxgAVmFipMuQtJC1E6blnzeMCJWiMEYAOYsARHYCU5qJZs4AfCaEA6ADb0NlAAFjjYuGAwAPymMJSIKBgohIqkYNqkSvz+gdYhYbgATNEwGpSyXDA+1QLGqUrKOUGh4bgALCVlpeyV1T4qdZndvdVCg5kABgAkAN4QAL6zEAUwDiVrlHarizMCTXkt4TDs0SZDKvv5rcfrAGLIaJhIW5v3KC9nmRcBzSsnMXYks84jBfD8Dp95hNHABuYjEUCQEABfwgax4BKPZKOWHEAD0ACpVqwYMU3kgYB0gTByTAAOwwAAcNIeMGprBJtNY-DYHXJ7IAbGwGVyAJxsp4srCFYqFHm06mFIW0wrMwri-mS-gk-hk1n8KmS2n8Bn8ZkKyVtTmsto8tp8h7UtpCtoim3i6m05TFZTy1nU5TK1nKZnKDWOyUCkkCvVYAWGrC0gUMgXm-2SunWrB0nl0h2JDNCulu7Meo2sxnFRl+rDUxlBrCM5mM8MFrCikmi2MU0UJim00UM0Vp2tPLYEvHEIA)

That's not pretty, but it works.  The `n` parameter just keeps track of how long we want to recurse.  We use the `a` array to keep track of the current number (by looking at its length), and the `c3` and `c5` arrays keep track of whether the current number is divisible by 3 or 5 (again, by looking at their length).  Each recursion step adds an element to `a`, and to `c3` and `c5` if they are not their max lengths.  If they are their max lengths then we wrap around to `[]`.  The `s` string accumulates the output.

We can translate that fairly directly to a *type*:

```
type FizzBuzz<
  N extends number = 101,
  C3 extends any[] = [0],
  C5 extends any[] = [0],
  A extends any[] = [0],
  S extends string = ""
> =
  A['length'] extends N ? S : FizzBuzz<
    N,
    C3['length'] extends 2 ? [] : [0, ...C3],
    C5['length'] extends 4 ? [] : [0, ...C5],
    [0, ...A],
    `${S}${S extends "" ? "" : " "}${C3['length'] extends 0 ?
    C5['length'] extends 0 ? "FizzBuzz" : "Fizz" :
    C5['length'] extends 0 ? "Buzz" : A['length']
    }`
  >

type FF = FizzBuzz
//   ^?
/* "1 2 Fizz 4 Buzz Fizz 7 8 Fizz Buzz 11 Fizz 13 14 FizzBuzz 16 17 Fizz 
    19 Buzz Fizz 22 23 Fizz Buzz 26 Fizz 28 29 FizzBuzz 31 32 Fizz 34 Buzz 
    Fizz 37 38 Fizz Buzz 41 Fizz 43 44 FizzBuzz 46 47 Fizz 49 Buzz Fizz 52 
    53 Fizz Buzz 56 Fizz 58 59 FizzBuzz 61 62 Fizz 64 Buzz Fizz 67 68 Fizz 
    Buzz 71 Fizz 73 74 FizzBuzz 76 77 Fizz 79 Buzz Fizz 82 83 Fizz Buzz 86 
    Fizz 88 89 FizzBuzz 91 92 Fizz 94 Buzz Fizz 97 98 Fizz Buzz" */
```

[Playground link to TS type-only code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99#code/C4TwDgpgBAYglgLwQIQK5IDwCgpQHJQQAewEAdgCYDOUZqAtgEYQBOUAvFAIwAMXANDigBhAMyES5alACGZEAG0AuhygKeSwbmEBWCaUo05ilZ3WahAQX1Sj85avNaoAZRuGoVYCzhkA5qoARIFYAHwcVgoA5AA25H7AABZRKsQG0gQA-K5QAFywiCjoCNi4uHjO2qLRcf5JKe7SAExQ2Q756vxQAHS9YhZlIjo18fWpkh4ALK1qKh08Xb3dugNlnT29lqu4AAYAJADeLgC+h25ptlDBM9f5gVenB2Ijdcnj6TQ8rULaw7Gjb0anxu8CQaCQ9zuoIQkJ+QxeCUBFw8X2ygXBMLyUEsCLGcOOOyEoSwWFAkFgMFU0IxWAA9LSygA9TJYIA)

In order to evaluate `type FF = FizzBuzz`, the compiler must perform at compile time a computation equivalent to the `fizzBuzz()` Javascript.  If you inspect the type `FF` above in your IDE, you will be shown the string [literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) equivalent to the value logged at runtime with `fizzBuzz()`.

But the `FizzBuzz` and `FF` types don't contribute *anything* to the compiled JavaScript, since the entire type system is [erased](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-from-scratch.html#erased-types) upon compilation.  At runtime nothing happens at all.  The fact that there is a type `FF` whose value is a string representing running Fizz Buzz is a demonstration that this happened purely at compile time at the level of types.

Comment: That translation from functional runtime code to types is super cool. My answer helps I think, but your answer deserves the checkmark on this, as usual :)